# mod_wsgi русские символы в пути проблема

Tags: python, django

на винде локально работает без проблем.

на сервере. python 3.6  django 3.2  + apache2 mod_wsgi

когда пытаюсь создать папку с русскими буквами

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /uploads/тест/file.log
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 63-66: ordinal not in range(128)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://*/uploads/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82/file.log
Django Version: 3.2.15
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 63-66: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py, line 387, in wrapped
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.9
Python Path:    
['/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '*/public_html/crm',
 '*/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 20 Aug 2022 22:37:59 +0300


*/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
*/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
*/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/static.py, line 37, in serve
    if fullpath.is_dir(): …
/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py, line 1348, in is_dir
            return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode) …
/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py, line 1158, in stat
        return self._accessor.stat(self) …
/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py, line 387, in wrapped
            return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
```

подскажите как вылечить

НО. если запускаю скрипт cli

```
python manager.py вызов_тестового_скрипта
```

он исправно создает файл с русским именем.

я так понимаю проблема в кодировке mod_wsgi
Как ее исправить где указывать эту кодировку?

Answer (score 0):

вообщем перерыл весь инет. куча советов. Но я упорно не мог найти у себя на сервере где у меня конфиг apache wsgi. ТОчнее я нашел, но он пустой. там ничего нет.

Оказалось locale проблема в нем.
сделал 2 настройки в конфиге самого апача  apache2.conf

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
locale=en_US.UTF-8
```

и все заработало

помогла эта статья
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/625